# What is the proper way for a Windows service to fail?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have inherited a Windows service written in C#.  Under rare conditions it fails badly.  However, it isn't at all clear how to fail well. Ross Bennett states the problem elegantly at [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/226355-windows-service-how-does-one-make-service-fail-properly).  For the sake of simplicity I will just quote him here.

> Ahoy, Folks!
>
> I've been looking all over for this,
>   but I just can't seem to shake any
>   documentation out of the MSDN or from
>   Google. I've reviewed every .NET
>   article on developing Windows Services
>   in the MSDN I've located.
>
> I'm developing a Windows Service
>   application. This service reads its
>   configuration data from the system
>   registry (HKLM) where it was deposited
>   by another "manager" application. No
>   problems there.
>
> The service uses a worker thread to do
>   its work. The thread is created in the
>   OnStart() and signaled/joined/disposed
>   in the OnStop(). Again, no problems.
>
> Everything works beautifully when:
>
> 1. The system administrator has set up everything properly, and
> 2. the foreign network resources are all reachable.
>
> But of course, we as developers simply
>   can't rely on:
>
> 1. The system administrator having set up everything properly, or
> 2. the foreign network resources being reachable.
>
> Really, what we need is for the
>   service application to have some way
>   of dying on its own. If a network
>   resource goes down, we need the
>   service to stop. But more to the
>   point, we need the SCM to know it has
>   stopped on its own accord. SCM needs
>   to know that the service has
>   "failed"...and hasn't just been shut
>   down by someone.
>
> Calling "return" or throwing an
>   exception in the "OnStart()" method
>   isn't even helpful for services still
>   in the start-up process.. The SCM goes
>   merrily on and the process keeps
>   running in the Task Manager--though
>   it's not actually doing anything since
>   the worker thread was never created
>   and started.
>
> Using a ServiceController instance
>   doesn't do it, either. That appears to
>   the SCM as a normal shutdown--not a
>   service failure. So none of the
>   recovery actions or restarts happen.
>   (Also, there is MSDNful documentation
>   warning about the perils of a
>   ServiceBase descendant using a
>   ServiceController to make things
>   happen with itself.)
>
> I've read articles where people were
>   messing about with PInvoking calls to
>   the native code just to set the
>   "Stopped" status flag in the SCM. But
>   that doesn't shut down the process the
>   service is running within.
>
> I'd really like to know the Intended
>   Way of:
>
> 1. Shutting down a service from within the service, where
> 2. The SCM is appropriatedly notified that the service has "Stopped", and
> 3. The process disappears from the Task Manager.
>
> Solutions involving ServiceControllers
>   don't seem to be appropriate, if only
>   because 2 is not satisfied. (That the
>   Framework documentation specifically
>   contraindicates doing that carries a
>   good deal of weight, incidentally.)
>
> I'd appreciate any recommendations,
>   pointers to documentation, or even
>   well-reasoned conjecture. :-) Oh! And
>   I'm perfectly happy to entertain that
>   I've missed the point.
>
> Most cordially,
>
> Ross Bennett

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Best practice in native code is to call [SetServiceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686241(v=VS.85).aspx) with a non-zero exit code to indicate 1) it's stopped and 2) something went wrong.

In managed code, you could achieve the same effect by obtaining the SCM handle through [the ServiceBase.ServiceHandle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.servicehandle.aspx) and P/Invoke-ing the Win32 API.

I don't see why the SCM would treat this any differently than setting the `ServiceBase.ExitCode` property non-zero and then calling `ServiceBase.Stop`, actually.  P/Invoke is a bit more direct perhaps, if the service is in panic mode.

---

As noted in the comments (also see https://serverfault.com/questions/72318/set-up-recovery-actions-to-take-place-when-a-service-fails) if a process calls `SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED)` with a non-zero exit code, the Recovery Actions for the serice will *only* be done if the option "Enable Actions For Stops With Errors" (`sc.exe failureflag`) is ticked. -> System Event ID 7024

If a service process exits (`Env.Exit()`) or crashs without consulting the SCM, then the Recovery Actions will always be run. -> System Event ID 7031

Comment: The answer I was looking for is contained in this answer.  The concise answer is: Set the ServiceBase.ExitCode property non-zero and then call ServiceBase.Stop.

Comment: Tried this (both via managed API, and through PInvoke of SetServiceStatus), and this approach did not allow for the service to restart automatically if it is configured to do so.  It absolutely stops the service though.

Calling `Environment.Exit()` or throwing an exception and not catching it causes the "abnormal" termination that the OS seems to be looking for, for auto-restart-upon-failure.

Comment: @jglouie: See http://serverfault.com/q/72318/206739 for the solution to your issue.

Comment: @JEdwardEllis, the only issue with it is that the Event Log tells that "Service stopped successfully." (with Information, not Error label). Do you know how it can be addressed?

Answer (score 7):

I've found that Environment.Exit(1) works fine for me. I generally place it in a method that catches unhandled exceptions and log the problem before I stop it. It completely destroys the service, but the SCM also knows that it is shutdown. You can set the SCM to restart your service automatically when it goes down x amount of times. I find this is far more useful than writing your own restart/shutdown code.

Comment: Environment.Exit() probably works most of the time, but you are effectively kicking the chair out from under your process.  For example, if you were writing a file, the buffers won't get flushed to disk if you just hard-stop the process.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a (non-P/Invoke) equivalent for this, but the WinAPI way seems to be to call `SetServiceStatus` with a value of `SERVICE_STOPPED` and then wait for the SCM to shut you down. As a positive side-effect, it logs the failure of your service into the event log.

Here are some quotes from [the relevant part of the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686241.aspx):

> If a service calls SetServiceStatus with the dwCurrentState member set to SERVICE_STOPPED and the dwWin32ExitCode member set to a nonzero value, the following entry is written into the System event log:
>
> [...] <ServiceName> terminated with the following error: <ExitCode> [...]
>
> The following are best practices when calling this function:
>
> [...]
>
> - If the status is SERVICE_STOPPED, perform all necessary cleanup and call SetServiceStatus one time only. This function makes an LRPC call to the SCM. The first call to the function in the SERVICE_STOPPED state closes the RPC context handle and any subsequent calls can cause the process to crash.
> - Do not attempt to perform any additional work after calling SetServiceStatus with SERVICE_STOPPED, because the service process can be terminated at any time.

PS: In my opinion, if network resources are unavailable, the service should not stop but continue running, waiting for the resources to become available. Temporary network outages can happen, and they should not require manual intervention from the system administrator once the network is back up.

Comment: +1 that PS was just what i was looking for. suppose the key is to find some proper interval for checking availability then

Answer (score 2):

After some testing I found the following works in cases where you calling Stop might cause other issues:

```
        ExitCode = 1;
        Environment.Exit(1);
```

Just calling Environment.Exit doesn't make the SCM do fault handling, but first setting the ServiceBase ExitCode does.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the proper ExitCode as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893165/how-to-get-exception-error-code-in-c-sharp).
So the Windows Service Manager will give the right error text.

My OnStart in ServiceBase looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        DoStart();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Win32Exception w32ex = exp as Win32Exception;
        if (w32ex == null)
        {
            w32ex = exp.InnerException as Win32Exception;
        }
        if (w32ex != null)
        {
            ExitCode = w32ex.ErrorCode;
        }
        Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: The question you reference [How to get Exception Error Code in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893165/how-to-get-exception-error-code-in-c-sharp) tells how to get the exception code when calling a WMI routine via PInvoke.  It is in no way a general answer to this question.