# Printing error code on the console

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this C# windows application. Exceptions occur at times. When an exception occurs, I want to drill down on the Error Code for that exception and then fetch and print it.

Posting sample code

```
public void CreateSkill(int row)
        {
            try
            {
                Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.Skill skill = new Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.Skill();
                skill.name = "perl";
               // skill.description = "bowler";
                skill.expertiseLevel = "3";
                skill.ID = 1;
                Console.WriteLine(skillClient.CreateSkill(skill));
                Console.WriteLine(skill.ID);
                ExcelRecorder(null, row);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExcelRecorder(ex.Message, row);
            }
            finally
            {
                System.GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

ExcelRecorder() is a method which prints the exception message in a cell in an excel sheet. 
I want to print the exception as well as the error code in my excel sheet. How do I fetch this error code through my code?

Posting an image

[image]

Comment: There is a similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893165/how-to-get-exception-error-code-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893165/how-to-get-exception-error-code-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
try { 

}
catch(Exception e) {
    int code = e.HResult;
}
```

or even:

```
try { 

}
catch (Exception e){ 
    var Wex = e as Win32Exception;
    int code =  Wex.ErrorCode;
};
```