# Trying to get exception code from .NET 3.5 without success

Tags: c#, web-services, exception, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a web service. Within a method, I have a try-catch block. Then within it, I would like to get the exception code.

I have tried below:

```
catch (Exception e){  
    var w32ex = e as Win32Exception;
    if(w32ex == null) {
        w32ex = e.InnerException as Win32Exception;
    }    
    if(w32ex != null) {
        int code =  w32ex.ErrorCode;
        // do stuff
    }    
    // do other stuff   
}
```

... that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893165/how-to-get-exception-error-code-in-c-sharp) but in my case, it is not working: When casting exception e as Win32Exception I get a null and also once I get a null and I try to cast `e.InnerException` as `Win32Exception` I get null as well.

Below a screenshot with my exception:

[image]

As you can see there is a `HResult` code.

Comment: Might it be that the exception is not of type (or derived from) Win32Exception?

Comment: @hormberg The exception that is thrown is of type System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException. How can I get the error code from this?

Comment: var v = e.HResult;

Comment: @hormberg I am using NET 3.5 and I cannot access it. I know this is possible from NET 4.5 and later...

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, you're catching an instance of **SoapException**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception?view=netframework-3.5
This class doesn't inherit from **Win32Exception**, that's why the type cast operator returns **null**. You should be able to get **HResult** field right from the base **Exception** class (even in .Net 3.5, according to the docs):

```
catch (Win32Exception w32ex)
{  
    // Put your current code here...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    int hResult = ex.HResult;
    // Handle HRESULT error code here...   
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet on how to get error code? I have tried without success.

Comment: @user1624552 Why do you need this "error code"? What are you trying to catch here?

Comment: Because I need to do some stuff only when this type of error is thrown. Exception can be the same but error codes can vary. so I need to identify exactly what error code is.

Comment: .. and Yes, you are right, the exception that is thrown is of type System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException so how can I get the error code from there?

Comment: @user1624552 I added the code snippet to the answer.