# How to get exception code in C# catch block

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

In the try catch block want to get the catch exception code, we know that 404: not found, 400: bad request. In my catch block want to get exception code. How to get exception code in C# catch block.

```
 try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: The `Exception` class is related to C# exception and 4XX are HTTP code statuses. You should handle the HTTP Codes based on the expected exceptions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893165/how-to-get-exception-error-code-in-c-sharp - Have you checked this?

Answer (score 3):

You can just  catch the WebException, and then, check the ProtocolError and status code.

```
}
catch(WebException e) {
    if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
        Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Keep in mind you can still add another `catch(Exception e)` after this catch if you want to do other things with other exceptions.

Comment: You are totally right. Edited answer for completeness! Ty!