# Showing custom error message while starting the windows service through services.msc

Tags: c#, error-handling, windows-services

[image: Generic error while starting the service]

While starting the installed service through `service.msc`, if the start up fails then windows shows a generic message in the pop up. But, in certain cases, we want to propagate a meaningful message here explaining why the service did not start, for example, if the customers fail to configure few things during installation.

Is there any way in `C#` through which we can achieve this functionality?

Comment: I hope this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456819/how-can-i-set-up-net-unhandledexception-handling-in-a-windows-service
setting up

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158772/handle-exception-on-service-startup?rq=1

Comment: I don't think a custom message is possible. You should explore Gaurav's link... basically you will need to look into the event log or dump the error somewhere you can read it.

Comment: are you starting the service manually from service.msc or from c# code ?

Comment: Catch the exception and set an `ExitCode` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.exitcode) to a value that Windows already knows (and rethrow), for example 1610 will display a nice *"The configuration data for this product is corrupt. Contact your support personnel."* message. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699- and also you can add information to the Event Log using `ServiceBase.EventLog` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.eventlog

Answer (score -1):

Try this method to display a custom message on starting failure

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args){
try
{
    // Perform startup tasks here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Display a custom message in the event of an error
    throw new Exception("Service failed to start. Error: " + ex.Message);
}}
```

Similarly, you can use OnContinue, OnPause, and OnStop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If an exception is thrown and doesn't show its message, how would throwing another exception make a difference? Please explain.

Comment: This does not work. The exception message is not available on UI